# How to grab all the characters from a file

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an input that has 20 characters (char) and I am using a dynamic 2D array to store them in. I have to read the characters from a file. To test that I have all of my characters, I try printing out what the program is reading in.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *key;
    key = new char[20];
    string *studentName;
    studentName = new string[4];
    char *testResults[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        testResults[i] = new char[21];
    }
    ifstream in;
    in.open("Ch12_Ex2Data.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        in >> key[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        in >> studentName[i];
        string ans;
        getline(in, ans);
        in.ignore(0, ' ');
        for(int j = 0; j < 21; j++){
            //in >> ans;
            if(ans[j] != ' '){
                testResults[i][j] = ans[j];
            }
            else{
                testResults[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Key: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
        cout << key[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << studentName[i] << " ";
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            cout << testResults[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    in.close();
    /* for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        delete [][] testResults;
    } */
    delete [] key;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        delete [] testResults[i];
    }
    /* delete [] testResults; */
    delete [] studentName;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I posted them as images

Comment: Post the text, not images. See  [mre].

Comment: Pictures of text are discouraged at StackOverflow for several reasons. One being the reader can't save the picture and load it into a compiler and get a working program to test.

Comment: for some reason I am not able to upload my c++ code. The system is screaming something about the code was not efficient enough to upload

Comment: In the editor type ``` press enter paste the code then press enter and type ``` again + enter. With that said if you post too many lines the system may reject the code because you have too little content in the question. It does not want code only questions.

Comment: Most of this code is unnecessary. There is no need to use `new[]` for fixed-length arrays, especially such small arrays. And most of the loops can be replaced with single calls to `cin.get(buffer,size)`/`cin.read(buffer,size)` and `cout.write(buffer,size)`. It would also help to see what the actual `.txt` file looks like.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need to dynamically allocate your variables.  If you are dynamically allocating arrays, consider using `std::vector` that can expand dynamically at runtime.

Comment: I have to dynamically allocate for a homework assignment

Answer (score 1):

In order to read from a file you need to include `<fstream>` at the top, and then initialize an `ifstream` object with the file name. And finally use `get(charName)` to get a single character:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile{"myfile.txt"};

    char charName{};

    while (inFile.get(charName))
    {
        // here is where you store each char
        // which will be provisionally stored in charName each iteration
    }

    // here is where you print your char array

    return 0;

}
```

Unfortunately, you didn't explain exactly how your 2D array is implemented, but the above is the essentials for reading from a file.